# "AutoReconnect: master has changed" is raised but all the recent replset logs are normal

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My mongoDB version is 2.2.0 and pymongo version is 2.3

I use the following API

```
conn=Connection('mongodb://xxxx:yyyy@aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:27017,eee.fff.ggg.hhh:27017,iii.jjj.kkk.lll:27017',replicaSet='myset',max_pool_size=20,auto_start_request=False)
```

to connect, and get collection as follow

```
collection=conn["myDB"]["myCollection"]
```

But when I iterate some query results

```
cursor=collection.find({"key":key})
for item in cursor:
    #do something with item['id']...
```

,I got "AutoReconnect: master has changed" exception from this line "for item in cursor:" occasionally.

I checked recent replset logs but they are all normal as usual. Is any suggestion to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: you are saying that the mongod logs indicate that the primary never changed during the time that your application got this error?

Answer (score 0):

If your URI includes an arbiter you should try removing it. Primaries and secondaries are fine to leave in, of course.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/anvtzVUqBRU